# Solr find all documents that contains a given point in a bbox

Tags: solr, geolocation

I have documents that are containing a bbox field: `"bbox__minX":-3.0029111,
"bbox__minY":56.72292997,
"bbox__maxX":-1.6804557,
"bbox__maxY":57.44159763,
"bbox":"ENVELOPE(-3.0029111, -1.6804557, 57.44159763, 56.72292997)",`
and I'd like to write a query that will return all documents that have a given point inside. One solution is whit: 
`q={!field%20f=bbox}Contains(ENVELOPE(-0.272308,-0.272308,51.657728,51.657728))` but here I'm doubled the point to simulate a rectangle (should be a better way).
Any better idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried `Contains(POINT(-0.272308, 51.657728))`? .. but [according to the docs](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/spatial-search.html): "To search, you can use the {!bbox} query parser, or the range syntax e.g. [10,-10 TO 15,20], or the ENVELOPE syntax wrapped in parenthesis with a leading search predicate. The latter is the only way to choose a predicate other than Intersects." Not sure if intersects would trigger against a point, but it seems that for anything other than the intersects operator, ENVELOPE is a necessity for a bbox field.

Comment: Yes I tried, and not working, error message: error: {
metadata: [
"error-class",
"org.apache.solr.common.SolrException",
"root-error-class",
"java.text.ParseException"
],
msg: "Unable to parse shape given formats "lat,lon", "x y" or as WKT because java.text.ParseException: Expected a number input: POINT(-0.272308, 51.657728))",
code: 400
}

Comment: I guess that's because of the limitation described - in that case you'll have to use ENVELOPE or see if Intersects works.